# Adding string 'm2' to arithmetic result

Tags: sql-server

When I have

```
case 

  when p.okres_nazev like '%Praha%'

   then cast(isnull(RealEstateTax_Suma,0) / 7 / 2 as varchar (30)) +' m2'
```

It gives me error

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.00 m2' to data type int.`

I want the result + m2 . So something like 30 m2

UPDATE :
the query looks like

```
SELECT a.custkey,
       a.dt,
       a.RealEstateTax_Suma,
       a.RealEstateTax_pocet,
       p.psc,
       CASE
         WHEN p.okres_nazev LIKE 'Praha' 
              THEN CAST(isnull(RealEstateTax_Suma, 0) / 7 / 2 AS VARCHAR (30)) + ' m2'
         ELSE 0
       END AS VelikostNemovitosti
FROM   wspace.dbo.DP_CustPayments_v3 a
       JOIN dmr.Cust c
         ON a.custKey = c.CustKey
            AND c.LastRecFlg = 1
       LEFT JOIN wspace.dbo.tp_GEO p
              ON c.PostZIPCode = p.psc
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the query? It looks like the error may be coming from elsewhere.

Comment: What is the end purpose for the data? If this is to indicate area (square meters) would you not be better adding the `m2` client side?

Comment: The concatenation to `0.00 m2` is obviously working OK. But presumably one of the other branches of the `case` evaluates to `int`. Therefore the whole column needs to cast to `int`

Comment: DavidG i updated the query but i dont think that the error is coming from elsewhere..

Comment: Martin Smith - so its because of the "else 0" ?

Comment: Yes, that would need to be `else '0'`. There look to be other possible issues there too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `else 0`. Change it to `else '0 m2'` and it should work.

The thing is, the result of the `case` always has to be the same type. The `0` in the `else` clause is an integer, so it tries to convert the `varchar` in the other case to an `int`, which doesn't work.

However, you shouldn't be doing that in the database anyway. Adding `m2` and handling `null` values should really be done in the presentation layer, rather than in SQL.

Also, `like` doesn't work that way - you need to use e.g. `like 'Praha%'`, otherwise you're really just doing `= 'Praha'`.